# Algorithm for filtering top-level directories among a list of paths, C#

Tags: c#, filter, path, directory

Input:

```
/dir1
/dir1/subdir
/dir1/subdir/sub-subdir
/dir2
```

Output should be:

```
/dir1
/dir2
```

Comment: Theres no algorithm, theres msdn documentation..

Comment: "find the second `/` and stop there"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
string inputDir = "/dir1/subdir/sub-subdir";
string [] Split = inputDir.Split(new Char [] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
string outputDir = Split[0];
```

Comment: Thanks ! actually we need Split[0] and Split[1], because the first occurrence is just the drive itself and if i needed just the root, there's already a filesysteminfo.root property for that. And that actually made this topic like a duplicate to this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599711/how-do-i-extract-a-substring-from-a-string-until-the-second-space-is-encountered

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> result= new List<string>();  

foreach (string i in input)
{
   string[] tmp = i.split(@"/");
   result.add(@"/" + tmp[0]);
}
```